# Delegate method occasionally not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

Everything works fine with my custom `UIImagePickerController`, except for a random case every 4 or 5 times when the following delegate method is not called:

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

It only happens with video recording. I'm able to stop the video capture, but then the delegate method is not called on a rather random basis.

What could I be missing? Would the fact that the `UIImagePickerController` class is dismissed (`dismissModalViewController`) have anything to do with it not being called? Running out of ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that dismissing the `UIImagePickerController` right after `[camera stopVideoCapture]` was the problem. If I wait to dismiss it once the delegate method was called, then no problem occurs. Note that this is only an issue when doing video.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate object is dismissing the picker object, right?

Comment: No, the picker itself is the delegate. The picker is created and handled in a view controller.

Comment: I think either you don't mean that because you don't understand delegates, or you do mean that and don't understand delegates. If an object is a delegate of itself, that's normally a good sign you're doing it wrong...

Comment: It's a modified version of this BTL Utilities code. https://github.com/pmark/Helpful-iPhone-Utilities/blob/master/BTL%20Utilities/BTLFullScreenCameraController.h

Comment: Should I make the UIViewController the delegate for it? Is there a problem the way it is set up now? (see link above... it's a stripped down version of that)

Comment: Yes, try changing the delegate to a separate object

Comment: No, I changed the delegate from the UIImagePickerController itself to the view controller, and the bug still exists.